# pandas combining AB groups with BA, discarding BA

Tags: python, database, pandas

```
+-----------------------+----------------+--------------------+
| route_group_essential | essential_move | non-essential_move |
+-----------------------+----------------+--------------------+
| from_to               |                |                    |
| placeA>placeB         |           11.0 |               11.0 |
| placeB>placeA         |              0 |                2.0 |
| placeC>placeD         |            3.0 |                1.0 |
| placeD>placeC         |            2.0 |                1.0 |
+-----------------------+----------------+--------------------+
```

I want to combine A>B and B>A rows and sum up its values, discarding one row.

Expected output :

```
+-----------------------+----------------+--------------------+
| route_group_essential | essential_move | non-essential_move |
+-----------------------+----------------+--------------------+
| from_to               |                |                    |
| placeA>placeB         |           11.0 |               13.0 |
| placeC>placeD         |            5.0 |                2.0 |
+-----------------------+----------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: What is `print (df.index)` ?

Comment: @jezrael With `print(df.head(1).index)`, it shows me ```Index(['placeA>placeB'], dtype='object', name='from_to')```

Comment: Removed first solution from answer, can you check it?

Comment: Please refer to this question for your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62815459/remove-reversed-pairs-across-columns-pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If first column is index is created new helper `Index` by sorted tuples:

```
g = df.index.map(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x.split('>'))))
```

And then before aggregation is converted index to column by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = (df.reset_index()
        .groupby(g)
        .agg({'from_to':'first',
              'essential_move':'sum',
              'non-essential_move':'sum'})
        .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
                from_to  essential_move  non-essential_move
0         placeA>placeB            11.0                13.0
1         placeC>placeD             5.0                 2.0
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for help.! You are true programmer! ```before : 
route_group_essential                        essential  non-essential
from_to                                                              
Busan Buk-gu>Busan Buk-gu                         11.0           11.0
Busan Buk-gu>Busan Haeundae-gu                     NaN            2.0``` ```after : 
                            from_to  essential  non-essential
0         Busan Buk-gu>Busan Buk-gu       11.0           11.0
1    Busan Busanjin-gu>Busan Buk-gu        2.0            4.0```