# Remove reversed pairs across columns (Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
Group1    Group2    Sim
 A         A        1.0
 A         B        0.5
 A         C        0.8
 B         B        1.0
 B         A        0.5
 B         C        0.7
 C         C        1.0
 C         A        0.8
 C         B        0.7
```

The `Group1` and `Group2` columns represent two group pairs and the `Sim` column represents the Jaccard similarity.

The difficulty is this: the pairwise Jaccard calculation resulted in repeating pairs across the two Group columns.

So, for example, across the Group columns: `A,B == B,A`; `A,C == C,A`; and so on.

I am struggling to figure out this question: how can I remove the redundant/reversed pairs across the two columns? (Computational limitations on the much larger real dataset require the removal of redundancies.)

I am expecting the following output:

```
Group1   Group2   Sim
A        B        0.5
A        C        0.8
B        C        0.7
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for anything complicated. Borrow [this trick](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/cross-join-unique-combinations/5152/3) for getting unique pairs after a SQL cross-product, you can just select for when Group1 < Group2

```
df[df["Group1"] < df["Group2"]]
```

resulting in

```
  Group1 Group2  Sim
1      A      B  0.5
2      A      C  0.8
5      B      C  0.7
```

If you also want to include the identity distances change `>` to `>=`.

This will be more efficient than the accepted answer as sorting is expensive.

Comment: I rechecked the code, and yours is much simpler and faster. No need for the sort. this is the correct answer. OP should pick this.

Answer (score 2):

Sort the first two columns row wise with [numpy sort](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html), get rows where Sim [count](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.size.html) is greater than 1, and finally [drop the duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).

```
df.loc[:, :2] = np.sort(df.filter(like="Group"))

df.loc[df.groupby(["Group1", "Group2"]).Sim.transform("size") > 1].drop_duplicates()


    Group1  Group2  Sim
   1    A      B    0.5
   2    A      C    0.8
   5    B      C    0.7
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks!!